# Can I create a time dimension from a datetime column in fact table in my database?

Tags: olap, olap-cube, mondrian

I am trying to create my first OLAP Cube.
My fact table has a date_time column in the format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" and I would like to use this column to create a dimension so the user can segment the results in months.

The tutorials I've found always have a time dimension table, which is not my case (I only have the date_time column directly in my fact table).

Is it possible to use the column to segment the results in months?

(I am using mondrian schema workbench to create the schema)